# Hide app without widget support from Android launcher widgets menu

Tags: java, android, widget

I'm developing an app which doesn't provide a real widget at a time. The user can add a shortcut to home screen by pressing a button inside my app, but I want my app **not** to be shown in the widget gallery of Android launchers. Currently the app is shown in the widget gallery, but dragging and dropping it to the desktop opens my app with an empty activity. How can I stop the app from showing in the widget gallery of launchers?